# delete column in TextWrangler (too large data - Option key and drag is not an option)

Tags: mac, textwrangler

I have a question regarding TextWrangler. I need to delete a column, but my data is so large that it is impossible to just hold down the Option key and then drag to make a rectangular selection (it would take forever to get to the end of the column). Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is formatted as comma-separated, tab-separated, or any other kind of repeated separation, you can use a spreadsheet tool like Excel.  Open the text file use Excel's open with menu and it should prompt you how to read the file (comma-separated, etc.).  Load each column of data into a spreadsheet column, delete the column you don't want, save it back out.  Excel's save options are more limited (comma- and tab-separations only, I think), so you might need to post-process the file to replace the commas or tabs with the original separation character.  But TextWrangler should be able to handle that, as well as numerous Terminal commands too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I modified the file in Excel and saved it as a txt file. However, when I try to open the txt file, I just get a note: The document “z32_NegArNeuArdiff_hwe0001_maf01_geno05” could not be opened.

Comment: That's an error from Text wrangler?  Can you open it in anything else like Text Editor?  Oh, is it still open in Excel?  Excel might be locking it.

Comment: Ups, it was still open in Excel...now it works! It is just not consistantly tab-separated, but that is probably because the columns were separated with a different amount of spaces in different rows to begin with.